# Streamparse calling next_tuple continuously

Tags: python, apache-storm, apache-kafka, stream-processing

I'm trying to write a simple Storm topology in Python using Streamparse. Everything is working for me except the simple Kafka spout that I wrote - it seems to just continuously call "next_tuple". My bolts are fairly slow, so the system seems to very quickly explode in memory.

Launching the topology, I tried to set topology.max.spout.pending to 1 to prevent it from adding too many messages to the topology.

```
lein run -m streamparse.commands.run/-main topologies/.clj -t 100 --option 'topology.max.spout.pending=1' --option 'topology.workers=1' --option 'topology.acker.executors=1'
```

However, the result is still this, despite the bolts being much slower:

```
24790 [Thread-16-metadata-spout] INFO  backtype.storm.spout.ShellSpout - Shell msg: ----NEXT TUPLE----
24942 [Thread-16-metadata-spout] INFO  backtype.storm.spout.ShellSpout - Shell msg: ----NEXT TUPLE----
24944 [Thread-16-metadata-spout] INFO  backtype.storm.spout.ShellSpout - Shell msg: ----NEXT TUPLE----
24946 [Thread-16-metadata-spout] INFO  backtype.storm.spout.ShellSpout - Shell msg: ----NEXT TUPLE----
25143 [Thread-16-metadata-spout] INFO  backtype.storm.spout.ShellSpout - Shell msg: ----NEXT TUPLE----
25144 [Thread-16-metadata-spout] INFO  backtype.storm.spout.ShellSpout - Shell msg: ----NEXT TUPLE----
25350 [Thread-16-metadata-spout] INFO  backtype.storm.spout.ShellSpout - Shell msg: ----NEXT TUPLE----
......
```

My simple Kafka spout:

```
class MetadataSpout(Spout):

    def initialize(self, stormconf, context):
        self.log('----CONFIG: %s----' % stormconf)
        k = KafkaClient(os.getenv('KAFKA'))
        self.consumer = SimpleConsumer(k, 'vacuum', 'metadata')

    def next_tuple(self):
        self.log('----NEXT TUPLE----')
        messages = self.consumer.get_messages(count=os.getenv('BATCH_COUNT', 20))
        self.emit([json.dumps([m.message.value for m in messages])])
```

My bolts have just the default configuration, but take a significant amount of time to complete the process() method. I cannot figure out how they could be the problem, but I can post if they're relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Solved, thanks to the great Streamparse team](https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse/issues/111)

"topology.max.spout.pending only has an effect if your spout is reliable. You'll need to specify the optional tup_id parameter to emit to give each tuple a unique ID. Once you do that, all should be well."

After specifying a UUID for the emitted tuples, this issue was solved.